The target group with targetGroupArn XXX does not have an associated load balancer
I have this error, I guess it means target group can't find the load balancer.
The target group with targetGroupArn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:678100228XXX:targetgroup/cm-dev-LBhtt-K30XQPPERISV/736d9ebb66636807 does not have an associated load balancer

My source code is like this below.
My creating order is  ECS service,loadbalancer,listener and targetGroup
In this order why targetGroup can't find the loadbalancer?
const ecsLiffService = new ecs.FargateService(this, "LiffService", {
  cluster: props!.cluster,
  taskDefinition: taskDefinitionLiff,
  desiredCount: desiredCount,
  vpcSubnets: resourceName.subnet_ids(vpc, this, "fargate_liff"),
  assignPublicIp: true,
  securityGroups: [liffServiceSg],
  enableExecuteCommand: true,
  serviceName: serviceName,
});

const lb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "LB", {
  vpc: props!.cluster.vpc,
  loadBalancerName: loadBalancerName,
  internetFacing: internetFacing,
  vpcSubnets: resourceName.subnet_ids(vpc, this, "alb_liff"),
  securityGroup: liffLbSg,
});

const listener = lb.addListener("Listener_liff", { port: 80 });

const targetGroup = listener.addTargets("ECS_liff", {
  protocol: elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
  port: 80,
  targets: [ecsLiffService],
  targetGroupName: ecsInfos["targetGroup80"],
});
targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({
  path: "/",
  port: "8080",
});

const cert_arn =
  "arn:aws:acm:ap-northeast-1:678100228XXX:certificate/7921a950-6d81-44f4-a13c-09fa5d6bc436";
const cert = elb.ListenerCertificate.fromArn(cert_arn);

var listener443 = lb.addListener("https-listener", {
  certificates: [cert],
  port: 443,
});

const targetGroup443 = listener443.addTargets(`ECS_liff-${targetEnv}443`, {
  protocol: elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
  port: 80,
  targets: [ecsLiffService],
  targetGroupName: ecsInfos["targetGroup443"],
});
targetGroup443.configureHealthCheck({
  path: "/",
  port: "8080",
});

listener443.addAction("https-default-action", {
  action: elb.ListenerAction.fixedResponse(404, {
    contentType: "text/html",
    messageBody:
      "Cannot route your request; no matching project found for ol 443 listener.",
  }),
});

